# Actuarial theory of interest question with effective discount

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I have spent several hours trying to solve this problem. $A$ and $B$ both open up new bank accounts at time $0$. The principle for $A$ (the amount deposited at $t=0$) is $100$. The principle of $B$ is $50$ (the amount deposited at $t=0$). Each account earns an annual discount rate of $d$. The amount of interest earned in $A$ during the 11th period is equal to $X$. The amount of interest earned in $B$ during the 17th period is equal to $X$. Calculate X.

Given that we are dealing with effective discount rate, for $A$ and $B$ we have $a(t)^{-1} = (1-d)^t$ clearly the amount of interest earned is $(1-d)^t$ for both $A$ and $B$. This means that $(1-d)^{11}=(1-d)^{17}$ 
Is this the correct set up? if not why? Given that the principles are $100, 50$ we have:

$\frac{100}{(1-d)^{11}}=\frac{50}{(1-d)^{17}}$ that is if we are setting the amount functions equal to each other during the $17$ and $11$ period. I thought this would translate to $50(1-d)^{11} = 100(1-d)^{17}$ then substituting $X$ for $(1-d)^{17}$ and $(1-d)^{11}$ we have something that makes no sense $50X=100X$ which gives $X=0$ after solving. If I don't substitute for $X$ I have $50(1-d)^{11}=100(1-d)^{17} \to 50=100(1-d)^6$ which translates to $\frac{1}{2}=(1-d)^{6}$ which gives a decimal less than one. The answer is $38.88$ I have no idea where I am going wrong. What am I missing? Am I even any where close on my thought processes?

Comment: You are comparing the values of the accounts at the end of year $11$ and year $17$, not the amounts earned in those years.  The amount earned in year $n$ is the value at $t=n$ minus the value at $t=n-1$.

Comment: @saulspatz I dont see how I am not comparing the amounts earned in those years because I was using the amount function for effective rates of discounts

Comment: am I supposed to use d to find i for those periods?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why it's stated in terms of discount instead of interest, but I don't see why it matters.  $a(17)=A(1+i)^{17},\ a(16)=A(1+i)^{16}$  The amount earned in period $17$ is $A[(1+i)^{17}-(1+i)^{16}]$.  If your discount calculation is equivalent to this, well and good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of interest earned in A during the 11th period is equal to $100\cdot (q^{11}-q^{10})$, where $q=1+i$ and $i$ is the interest. Equivalently for $B$. Thus the equation is

$$100\cdot (q^{11}-q^{10})=50\cdot (q^{17}-q^{16})$$

Dividing the equation by $50\cdot q^{10}$.

$$2\cdot (q-1)=(q^{7}-q^{6})$$

The (approximate) solution is $q=1.12246$

Thus $X=50\cdot (1.12246^{17}-1.12246^{16})=38.87749...\approx 38.88$